# Find a character in the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an attribute of HTML input element that has a value like this:

```
elements[1587f9aa-8a9e-4058-b1f3-d358041430c9][0][element-0][value]
```

How can I locate and get a number inside breckets [0] ? 
This number will change as well as the left and right parts ot the string, so I can't just extract the 48-th (or whatever) symbol.
The pattern gonna be the same all the time, even `[element-?][value]` part will be the same.

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: The regular expression should match `[` followed by a sequence of digits followed by `]`. Should be very simple. If you don't know regular expressions, read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: `string.split(']')[1].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`. Alternatively, you can try a regex. https://regex101.com/r/l1Nuw7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression, like this:

```
/elements\[[^\]]+\]\[(\d+)\]/
```

This is like saying, "Find string `elements[x][y]`, where `x != ']'` and `y is a number`"

You can then use the `match` method on a string to capture the matches. Parentheses in a regular expression will capture a sub grouping of characters (such as `y` in the above example).

Demonstration:

```js
$('div').each(function(i,e){
  var attr = $(e).attr('data-var');
  var matches = attr.match(/elements\[[^\]]+\]\[(\d+)\]/);
  console.log(matches[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-var="elements[1587f9aa-8a9e-4058-b1f3-d358041430c9][0][element-0][value]"></div>
<div data-var="elements[1587f9aa-8a9e-4058-b1f3-d358041430c9][1][element-1][value]"></div>
```

Comment: That is wrong approach. People do that because they think if the answer quickly, they will get more votes, and although it may be true, its better to post a complete answer. Have a good day :-)

Comment: in my understanding it's wrong. But as long as you edit and add explanation later, it's cool. Signing off. ☺

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string with `][` and get the element at position 1

```js
var string = 'elements[1587f9aa-8a9e-4058-b1f3-d358041430c9][0][element-0][value]';
console.log(string.split('][')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution:

use jQuery to get string (all except number in brackets) and then replace it with empty char:

```
string.replace(/elements\[[^\]]+\]\[|\]\[element.*/g, "");
```

working example: http://regexr.com/3g1l3

Comment: But my goal is to extract that number.

Comment: This function remove all except this number, should work for you. Regular expression find string, jQuery remove it (replace with empty char) and returns only number you want.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, will try it out.